# std::vector on forward declared type

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, forward-declaration, c++17

The following code seems to work correctly on Clang++ and GCC:

```
#include <vector>

class A {
private:
    int i;
    std::vector<A> children;
public:
    A& add();
};

A& A::add() { children.emplace_back(); return children.back(); }

int main() {
    A a;
    A& a2 = a.add();
}
```

When the data member `std::vector<A>` is declared, `A` is still an incomplete type. Same when using `std::vector<B>` and `B` was only forward declared with `class B;`.
It should work with `std::vector` since it only contains a pointer-to-`A`.

Is this guaranteed to work, or undefined behavior?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is undefined behavior in C++14 and earlier; well-defined in C++17 (if it's 17).

[res.on.functions]/p2, bullet 2.7:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - [...]
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for
>     that component.

In C++14 and earlier, `std::vector` does not "specifically allow" this. So the behavior is undefined.

For C++17, [N4510](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html), adopted at the committee's May 2015 meeting, relaxes this rule for `vector`, `list`, and `forward_list`.

Answer (score 1):

According to section "Template Parameters" from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) this might work (depending on the actual usage of the container) in C++17 standard, but not in C++14 and earlier. Probably you are using versions of the compilers that implement this part of C++17 standard.

Comment: Actually, the paper accepted for C++17 was accepted with only `std::list`, `std::forward_list` and `std::vector` so that GCC, Clang and MSVC are compliant out of the box.